# Why is PHP showing me this undefined function

Tags: php

Hi there I'm just trying to create a blog and I have stumbled upon this issue..

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_safe_query() in D:\xampp\htdocs\wd1_vtec_0100348514\pages\post_add.php on line 5

This is my code on that specific page..

```
<?php
// post_add.php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    include 'config.php';
    if(mysql_safe_query('INSERT INTO posts (title,body,date) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)', $_POST['title'], $_POST['body'], time()))
        echo 'Entry posted. <a href="post_view.php?id='.mysql_insert_id().'">View</a>';
    else
        echo mysql_error();
}
?>

<?php
include 'header.php';
?>

<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="title">Title</label></td>
            <td><input name="title" id="title" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="body">Body</label></td>
            <td><textarea name="body" id="body"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Post" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style1.css">



        <div id="menu">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="home.php" target="_self" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="session1.php" target="_self" >Sessions</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="session1.php" target="_self" >Session 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="session2.php" target="_self" >Session 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="session3.php" target="_self" >Session 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="session4.php" target="_self" >Session 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="session5.php" target="_self" >Session 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="session6.php" target="_self" >Session 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="session7.php" target="_self" >Session 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="session8.php" target="_self" >Session 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="session9.php" target="_self" >Session 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="session10.php" target="_self" >Session 10</a></li>
                <li><a href="session11.php" target="_self" >Session 11</a></li>
                <li><a href="session12.php" target="_self" >Session 12</a></li>
                <li><a href="session13.php" target="_self" >Session 13</a></li>
                <li><a href="session14.php" target="_self" >Session 14</a></li>



            </ul>

            <li><a href="blog.php" target="_self" >Blog</a></li>




    </ul>
    <div style="float:right">  <a class="btn btn-danger logout" href="logout.php" > Logout</a> </div>
    </div>







<?php include ('footer.php'); ?>
```

I have tried various ways around this but I am unsure of how to continue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: where do you think the method is defined?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a core function. Where did you get that code from?

Comment: Pressume it's a function from: [here](http://snipplr.com/view/22287/mysqlsafequery-to-prevent-sql-injection/) ?

Comment: @Darren Along with a bunch of others I found on Google ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Was thinking the same thing!

Comment: Here's one http://pastebin.com/8EcS9y1B and http://programanddesign.com/2009/06/ etc.

Comment: Just replace `if(mysql_safe_query` with `if(mysql_query` if using `mysql_` or `if(mysqli_query` if using `mysqli_` function. Yet by the looks of the rest of your functions, it's `mysql_`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have the method `mysql_safe_query()` defined. It isn't included in PHP. Add the following methods to `config.php`:

```
function mysqli_safe_string($value) {
    if(empty($value))           return 'NULL';
    elseif(is_string($value))   return '\''.mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($value)).'\'';
    elseif(is_numeric($value))  return $value;
    elseif(is_array($value))    return implode(',',array_map('mysqli_safe_string',$value));
    else                        return false;
}

function mysqli_safe_query($format) {
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(),1);
    $args = array_map('mysql_safe_string',$args);
    $query = vsprintf($format,$args);
    return mysqli_query($query);
}
```

Source: http://snipplr.com/view/22287/mysqlsafequery-to-prevent-sql-injection/ (first link that came up when I Googled it).

Notice that I changed everything to `mysqli_`, and not `mysql_`. `mysql_` has been deprecated for a while and I don't really know why people asking questions here still use it. Change all your `mysql_` methods to `mysqli_` including the ones for your DB connection configuration file.

Comment: And that doesn't matter. They'll keep using them while you offer a solution like the copy paste you posted above..

Comment: @Darren There's a extremely high likelihood that *Sally* is a she.

Comment: That function won't work, since it contains `mysqli_` functions - You'd need to modify it to make it work with OP's present code, since OP is using `mysql_`

Comment: @faintsignal Haha I didn't even notice that. 10 brownie points for you ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I initially made it so that it will work with OP's present code. Changed it because it's deprecated, and instructed OP to make the necessary changes. I'm so confused - what should I do...

Comment: We'll just leave it as that then. If OP has any questions, am sure the OP will. ;-) - time will tell.

Comment: [`This`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924107/why-is-php-showing-me-this-undefined-function#comment38727778_24924107) would be another option ;-)

Comment: @Darren On the other hand, I might be on the sh|t list if OP turns out to be Salvador. :)

Comment: @Darren the word is __deprecated__, not 'depreciated'.

Comment: @sevenseacat Thank you for spotting my negligence. It was early in the morning haha!